# Return list of files in a server as a json or text instead of the deafult "Index of" html page

Tags: nginx

I'm setting up a new server to host files. I need suggestions on how to return a JSON or text with the file names when i perform a GET request to that particular location.
I have not built an API service and would want to keep this as simple as possible.

OS - Ubuntu 18.04
Web Server used - NGINX

Here are the steps i have done -

- Created a folder called docs under /home/john/docs
- Have added this to my NGINX conf . Any request that is made to 
  /docs  will display the files under docs folder.

Have added this location block
    
        `location /docs {
        alias /home/john/docs/;
            autoindex on;
        }`

When I visit the page , as expected "Index of" is displayed and the list of files which can be downloaded is visible.
I would want to know if there is a way where i can return just the file names i.e I would want to receive a JSON or a list of all the files available instead of this page .
GET request to /docs can return a text or JSON . Currently i obtain this html

```
<html>
  <head><title>Index of /docs/</title></head>
  <body bgcolor="white">
    <h1>Index of /docs//</h1>
    <hr>
      <pre>
        <a href="../">../</a>
        <a href="v1.pdf">v1.pdf</a>  17-Aug-2019 06:24             1223345
        <a href="v2.pdf">v2.pdf</a>  17-Aug-2019 06:24             1223356
      </pre>
    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward with [autoindex_format](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex_format):

```
location /docs {
    alias /home/john/docs/;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_format json;
}
```

Comment: That worked ! Thanks a lot . Will upvote once i have enough creds :)